# x64 rounding inconsistency in cvRound() (_mm_cvtsd_si32)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, rounding-error

On x64 Windows using MSVC2013, I am using the `cvRound` function of OpenCV with the intention of round up from `x.5` values. I've come across an inconsistency where `cvRound(17.5f)` returns `18` (good!), but `cvRound(20.5f)` returns `20` and not `21` as expected

cvRound is simply implemented thus, so it seems to be an Microsoft inconsistency in `_mm_cvtsd_si32()`.

```
int  cvRound( double value )
{
    __m128d t = _mm_set_sd( value );
    return _mm_cvtsd_si32(t);
}
```

Can anyone suggest how/why this could be?

FWIW, `cvRound(20.5f + 1e-3f)` returns `21`.

Comment: Floating point can't represent numbers exactly, so algorithms using floating point cannot depend on it.

Comment: @stark is correct. If you haven't already read this, now I guess it's time: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: The other comments/answers here are correct. Note also that `_mm_cvtsd_si32()` is an intrinsic that maps to a single assembly instruction (`CVTSD2SI`), so the Microsoft compiler wouldn't really have any effect on its exact rounding behavior.

Comment: What is 17.5f converted to double?

Comment: @micka 17.5 -- it's a power of 2!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rounding behavior of the SSE instructions is configurable via the floating point environment (specifically, the MXCSR register).  There are [several IEEE rounding modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Rounding_rules).  The default rounding mode is round-to-nearest, ties-to-even, so if the value is exactly in the middle of two representable values, the result is rounded to the nearest even value.

Consider the following test program that demonstrates the different rounding modes in action:

```
#include <fenv.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Default:        %d\n", _mm_cvtsd_si32(_mm_set_sd(20.5)));
    fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    printf("FE_DOWNWARD:    %d\n", _mm_cvtsd_si32(_mm_set_sd(20.5)));
    fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    printf("FE_UPWARD:      %d\n", _mm_cvtsd_si32(_mm_set_sd(20.5)));
    fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);
    printf("FE_TONEAREST:   %d\n", _mm_cvtsd_si32(_mm_set_sd(20.5)));
    fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO);
    printf("FE_TOWARDZERO:  %d\n", _mm_cvtsd_si32(_mm_set_sd(20.5)));
}
```

Output:

```
Default:        20
FE_DOWNWARD:    20
FE_UPWARD:      21
FE_TONEAREST:   20
FE_TOWARDZERO:  20
```

Answer (score 7):

Small half-integers can be exactly represented by binary floating point -- 0.5 is a power of 2.

What is really going on is "rounding half to even."  This is a way to remove a bias which occurs when half-integers are always rounded up.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Comment: This answer nails the real issue. All the votes should go here.

Answer (score 1):

The rounding works like that for the same reason that this code prints that the values are equal (tested with MSVC2012)

```
float f1 = 20.4999999f;
float f2 = 20.5f;
if(f1==f2)
    printf("equal\n");
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html